# Determine end of message in socket stream

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous

I have a project with a server and a client using asynchronous socket connections.

I want to transmit an object from server to client. Unfortunately I have the problem, that sometimes the object isn't fully transmitted in one go. Therefore I need a way to determine when an object was fully transmitted. So I added a four-byte-head to the data transmitted to tell, how long the stream will be.

```
Server

private void Send(Socket handler, Packet packet)
    {
        byte[] byteData = ByteHelper.Serialize(packet).Data;

        byte[] byteDataLength = BitConverter.GetBytes(byteData.Length);

        byte[] transmissionData = new byte[byteDataLength.Length + byteData.Length];
        byteDataLength.CopyTo(transmissionData, 0);
        byteData.CopyTo(transmissionData, byteDataLength.Length);

        if (debug)
        {
            Status = "Sending "+packet.Type+"-packet to client.";
        }

        try
        {
            handler.BeginSend(transmissionData, 0, transmissionData.Length, 0, new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), handler);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Status = "[EXCEPTION]" + ex.Message.ToString();
        }
    }
```

The client receives the stream and evaluates the first four bytes to create a StateObject which has the right size. But I have the feeling that this is not really a good way to solve my problem. Is there a better way to do this?

```
Client

private void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        StateObject state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;
        try
        {
            Socket client = state.workSocket;

            int bytesRead = client.EndReceive(ar);

            if (bytesRead > 0)
            {
                do
                {
                    state = AdjustState(state);
                    if (state != null)
                    {
                        if (state.buffer.Length == state.bufferSize)
                        {
                            ProcessPacket(state);
                            receiveDone.Set();
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        receiveDone.Set();
                    }
                }
                while (state != null && state.tempBuffer.Length >= state.bufferSize);
                if (state != null)
                {
                    client.BeginReceive(state.tempBuffer, 0, state.tempBuffer.Length, 0, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), state);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("ReceiveCallback: " + ex.ToString(), "Client-Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }

private static StateObject AdjustState(StateObject state)
    {
        StateObject tempState = state;
        if (tempState.tempBuffer.Length >= 4)
        {
            byte[] sizeBytes = tempState.tempBuffer.Take(4).ToArray();
            int bufferSize = BitConverter.ToInt32(sizeBytes, 0);
            if (bufferSize == 0)
            {
                return null;
            }
            byte[] temp = tempState.tempBuffer.Skip(4).ToArray();
            Socket tempSocket = tempState.workSocket;
            tempState = new StateObject(bufferSize);
            tempState.BufferSet();
            if (temp.Length >= bufferSize)
            {
                tempState.buffer = temp.Take(bufferSize).ToArray();
                tempState.tempBuffer = temp.Skip(bufferSize).ToArray();
            }
            tempState.workSocket = tempSocket;
        }
        return tempState;
    }
```

**Solution**

Thanks to **usr** I've changed the bytesRead-Part in the ReceiveCallbackCode of the client to this. It seems to work now.

```
if (bytesRead > 0)
            {
                if (!state.bufferSet)
                {
                    state = AdjustState(state);
                    client.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, state.bufferSize, 0, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), state);
                }
                else
                {
                    if (state.buffer.Length == state.bufferSize)
                    {
                        ProcessPacket(state);
                        receiveDone.Set();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        client.BeginReceive(state.buffer, state.buffer.Length, state.bufferSize - state.buffer.Length, 0, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), state);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Sending the length first is a fairly common thing to do but I can't really make sense of this state object and how you're using it. Usually you get the length first, allocate a buffer of that size, and then make repeated calls to `(Begin)Receive` adjusting the `offset` and `size` values so that each call just writes to the correct part of the single allocated buffer, until you've received exactly the right amount of data. Maybe your code is equivalent but it's difficult to tell with so may allocations and creation of different arrays.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever the code is not equivalent because he cannot tolerate the length prefix to be split into parts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not making use of the return value from `EndReceive` (`bytesRead`). It signals how many bytes were received.

And in case `bytesRead == 0` you just do nothing which is probably not a proper response to the connection having ended.

And then, there is this unsynchronized busy-loop:

```
while (state != null && state.tempBuffer.Length >= state.bufferSize);
```

That's going to burn one CPU core for each client connection. Must solve this differently.

Comment: Okay. I have two questions now. 1. What should I do, when `bytesRead == 0`2. What is the problem with `while (state != null && state.tempBuffer.Length >= state.bufferSize);` exactly?

Comment: Ok. 1. This means the connection was (gracefully) closed. Do whatever you want in that case. Shut down the app? Log an error? Depends on what you *need*. 2. That loop will burn a CPU core until the condition is satisfied (right?). Your server will die of CPU load. Also, you lose all scalability benefits provided by async IO.